# Laravel5 deployment share env variables between both CLI and web server

Tags: php, nginx, environment-variables, fpm

I am deploying a Laravel app and a part of my build script is to run ./artisan migrate. While I can pass environment variables to web server by adding them to nginx site config in sites-available, they for obvious reasons do not get shared with CLI.

Is there a way to include the same env variables to both web server and CLI to use? I tried adding a config file with values to `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/` but it did not work.

My `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/env.conf`

```
[env]
env[APP_ENV] = production
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to create same file in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/pool.d/env.conf` or make symlink.

We assume, php-cli is installed.